# 21.10 Firefox Missing Profiles

Tags: firefox, 21.10

I upgraded 21.04 to 21.10 and have a couple of issues which I'll separate out. The first is Firefox will not launch. Or rather it does, but only  to give the error

```
Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible.
```

There doesn't seem to be any way around the error message. I had Firefox running successfully under 21.04 before the upgrade.

Comment: It could have to do with the fact that firefox is now installed as a snap instead of a deb-package. Depending on the location of your profile (snaps only have access to $HOME by default) you may need to configure permissions of the firefox snap. Alternatively you can still install the deb package. See the [Releae Notes](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/impish-indri-release-notes/21951) and [this discourse](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/feature-freeze-exception-seeding-the-official-firefox-snap-in-ubuntu-desktop/24210).

Comment: What do you get if you open a terminal and type `sudo firefox -P`

Comment: Does `sudo apt install firefox && sudo snap remove firefox` work?

Comment: [Firefox lost passwords, saved tabs, settings after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04](https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg6020064.html). I've lost everything too (now trying to get stuff manually from my profile), snaps are bogged.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. Here is what I did to quickly fix this issue.

1. Uninstall firefox snap with:

   ```
   sudo snap remove firefox
   ```
2. Install firefox snap with:

   ```
   sudo snap install firefox
   ```
3. Run snap with:

   ```
   snap run firefox
   ```

With the last command you should see the following lines in the terminal:

```
Importing existing firefox profiles from /home/xxxxxxx/.mozilla/firefox
Found default profile: xxxxxxxx.default
Import done in 1.826 s
```

After that all bookmarks and login/password should be back.

Comment: You have to do this while the previous .deb version is installed still!  See  https://askubuntu.com/a/1289004/14747. In 22.04 I had to reinstall the firefox .deb using these instructions: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04 .  I also had to use the `--allow-downgrade` flag according to here: https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2021/10/how-to-fix-an-upgraded-firefox-profile/

Comment: In my case during upgrade 20.04.5 > 22.04.1 profiles were not transferred for other than the primary user. The even faster fix was: **1.** close firefox **2.** `rm -rf ~/snap/firefox` **3.** `snap run firefox` (import will start). See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1969910 --- Note: I would be afraid that `sudo snap remove firefox` could affect profiles of all the users on the system :(

Comment: @pabouk-Ukrainestaystrong thanks a lot for your comment - I made it into an answer :)

Comment: The fix @Mathieu posted worked for me in a UTM-launched aarch64 Ubuntu 22.04 (and as a bonus it doesn't directly mess with the snap implementation which theoretically could change in future), though my CLI error was a bit different: ```missing profile snap.firefox.firefox.
Please make sure that the snapd.apparmor service is enabled and started
```

Answer (score 5):

The Firefox snap app is the default web browser in Ubuntu 21.10. You can uninstall the snap version and install the .deb version with the command:

```
sudo apt install firefox && sudo snap remove firefox
```

The .deb version of Firefox should be able to see your profile.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution that works for me was as follows:

1. close firefox
2. `rm -rf ~/snap/firefox`
3. `snap run firefox`

Upgrade from 20.04.5 > 22.04.1. Per https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1969910 and thanks to @pabouk for the solution above.