# 21.10 snap Firefox crashed tabs

Tags: firefox, snap, crash

I recently updated my desktop to Ubuntu 21.10. This defaults to a snap version of Firefox, and while it is slower to start, I could live with that. But the real problem was that, several times a day, I would be told that I had a crashed tab, and this message was in all tabs (of which I only had 3 or 4). The message included a button to restore the tabs, and while this always worked, it was annoying. As an experiment, I tried deleting the snap version and installing Firefox from apt (instructions [here](https://www.debugpoint.com/2021/09/remove-firefox-snap-ubuntu/)). Since doing this, the tab-crashing behavior is gone. So why would the snap version, and only the snap version, have this problem? This is a System76 Ratel Pro with 8 Gb of RAM. It currently has no System76 PPA, pure Ubuntu 21.04 install from ISO, then upgraded to 21.10.

Edit: I do not believe that the "21.10 Firefox Missing Profiles" question describes the same problem. The problem I encountered concerns Firefox running normally, and then asynchronously crashing. Repeatedly.

Comment: It's possible that the snap was updating out from under you. Hard to know without logs, but snapped applications historically have trouble when the snap hosting them is updated while they're running, moving directories around and updating confinement profiles, and so on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [21.10 Firefox Missing Profiles](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369493/21-10-firefox-missing-profiles)

Comment: Install deb version of firefox and check if tabs in it crash too.

Comment: The suggestion that it could be caused by updating while running is the first plausible explanation I have heard. But it seems to me that should not be allowed. If true, this seems like a fundamental design flaw in the Snap architecture. If a new version is available, the user should be notified so he or she can exit from it, take the update, and then restart the application.

Comment: In reply to pasman pasmański, yes, after doing that, there was no further occurrence of crashing tabs, as I wrote in my original post. It is confusing, but my question here was _why_ does the Snap version, and only the Snap version crash repeatedly (for me)?