# Browerpass in snap Firefox

Tags: firefox, snap

I just migrated from 21.04 to 21.10, and as a result, I'm now defaulting to Firefox snap package.

It seems this breaks Browerpass plugin, with this error:

```
Error: Error: Attempt to postMessage on disconnected port
```

It also seems to break Gnome extensions management from Firefox.

So, what are the possibilities/limits of Firefox snap package regarding plugins, especially those that rely on Native Messaging ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [21.10 Firefox Missing Profiles](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369493/21-10-firefox-missing-profiles) ← remove Snap of Firefox, install deb instead.

Comment: I would ask this possibilities/limits question in https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/feature-freeze-exception-seeding-the-official-firefox-snap-in-ubuntu-desktop/24210 . Gnome extensions management is already discussed in that thread. To me, it looks like another bug report for Mozilla (the author of the Snap), since I doubt that they intended to break add-ons. Replacing the Snap with a deb is only a temporary workaround; current plan is that the deb will no longer be made in 22.04 unless a community group steps up to adopt it.

Comment: @kanehekili I'd suggest keeping an open mind -- there are some big advantages to the change. It's all in the first post of the linked thread. Note that it's a testing and technical feedback thread for a decision that has already been made. It's not an opinion or complaint thread.