# Firefox profile (passwords, history etc) gone after upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: upgrade, firefox, 22.04

I've recently upgraded my ubuntu version from 20.04 to 22.04. After this my firefox is missing all my passwords and profile etc.

Is there any way to get them back, I did not anticipate this happening when I upgraded!

(After googling, I know that this issue is related to the new version being a snap and the old version being something else. I'm a long term Ubuntu user, but these terms mean little to me, and I choose ubuntu precisely because, in general, I don't have to be a computer scientist to get it working for my needs, so would appreciate answers in plain terms please)

Edit: have found an answer ([from here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369493/21-10-firefox-missing-profiles)) :

Uninstall firefox snap with:

sudo snap remove firefox
Install firefox snap with:

sudo snap install firefox
Run snap with:

snap run firefox
With the last command you should see the following lines in the terminal:

Importing existing firefox profiles from /home/xxxxxxx/.mozilla/firefox
Found default profile: xxxxxxxx.default
Import done in 1.826 s

This worked for me.

Comment: I guess you didn't have a Firefox Account set up before you upgraded. In all likelihood, that would have saved your bacon. Best set one up now if you don't have a backup of your old 20.04 instance FF setup.

Comment: Putting an answer in the Question is not a good practice. Although your question has been asked several times and a similar answer was given, you should add your solution as an Answer or delete your Question altogether.