# Favorites bar: orange dot for running Firefox missing

Tags: gnome, firefox, icons, favorites

I have Firefox as one of my favorites. When I open Firefox, the little "running dot" in the favorites bar is missing. So when I click the icon to return to the open instance, another instance opens instead.

When I remove Firefox as one of my Favorites, the orange dot appears, and clicking the icon returns me to the running instance.

I know I can go to "Activities" and find the window, but I'm in the habit of using the bar. But I'm wondering what would cause an app not to show a running dot. It may be just a Firefox problem, but the fact it shows when not a favorite suggests it might be an Ubuntu problem.

Edit: Running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, Firefox 100

Comment: First, right click on the icon to remove it, then when FF is running ater selecting it from `Activities`, right click the icon in the dock and select `Add to Favourites` then select from the `Dock` as normal.

Comment: We have no idea what version of Ubuntu and Firefox you might be running. Please add that information to your question: use "edit".

Comment: Thanks @vanadium.

Comment: @24601 doesn't work as indicated - once I drag the icon back above the line to make it a favorite the dot disappears.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that on a freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04 where Firefox is set as a favorite by default

Comment: @vanadium me neither on a fresh install even though I have removed the snap and installed the APT version. I'm still not sure that the OP has followed the suggested route in the steps outlined.

Comment: Ah, I think you guys are on to something. Because of the change to SNAP in 22.04, I had to migrate my profile from APT to SNAP following: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1288879/installed-firefox-to-migrate-from-classic-installation-to-snap . Maybe that had something to do with it?

Comment: Maybe @Colin. Is it not easier to create a Firefox account since when you log on to a new device (snap or APT) your profile will follow you. That is what I have done and it worked perfectly well pulling across all my Bookmarks in the process. Makes life with FF much easier 

Comment: @24601 I have one indeed. At the time I had a stack of tabs open that I wanted to follow me. Still, can hardly think that a profile migration would cause a disappearing dot??

Comment: stranger things have happened 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really an answer, but there's a [bug 1972545 here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1972545) and a [collection](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1960541) [of](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1944065) [other](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1950054) [bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1872475) on a similar effect.

One suggestion is that it may be that these are snaps: the snap has updated behind the scenes but Firefox (or other app) has not yet been restarted.  It is claimed that restarting Firefox will fix it (until the next time).

Comment: This is it! Closing and restarting Firefox has the little dot reappear. Thanks!